Firebase Storage file 403 using wget but downloadable via browser
I copied the download URL of an image file stored in Firebase Storage, it is accessible and can be download with browser but when I tried to use wget in a Linux server it is getting 403. Which one is at fault in this scenario? Does Firebase Storage domain have issue with this way of accessing file or it is the server running in Linux that is having issue?
wget -O sample.jpeg <THE_DOWNLOAD_URL_OF_FIREBASE_STORAGE_FILE>

I believe this is not a Firebase rule problem since it is still accessible even when I am not authenticated on other browser. The image url also has permanent token. The linux server is a Glitch static website.
Sample image
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/convenient-sabong.appspot.com/o/Devices%2F1666029723328%2FGooglePixelC___1_.jpg?alt=media&token=4751669f-600d-49a1-b031-7387105da7c7
Error


Can you confirm you still have the token in the query params of the URL when using wget?

@Dharmaraj yes, no changes has been made with the download url

I am unable to replicate the issue on my end. Any chances you could share a test URL and screenshot of the console when you run wget?

Do you have security rules enforced on storage?

@AlexanderN. I do have a basic rule allow read, write: if request.auth != null; on match /{allPaths=**} but it should not matter right because what I am using is the download URL which supposed to be accessible for public?

@Dharmaraj updated the question with both sample url and error log

I am unable to see the complete command that you run but can you try wrapping the URL in double quotes like: wget -O file.ext "https://....?token=..."

@Dharmaraj adding double quotes solves it on both wget and curl. Thanks a lot

If your URL contains any special characters like &, you must enclose your URL in double quotes. The URL in your CLI screenshot does not include the token from the URL. Try:
wget -O file.ext "https://....?token=***"


I think the terminal in Glitch has visual bug since the token is included during request, the screenshot above is the result after wget command. Anyway it really seems that the issue comes from the URL encoding, enclosing the URL with double quote fixed the problem.
